# How can I upload JPEG image without losing EXIF?

Tags: android, jpeg, retrofit2

Here is where I create the file's format

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new 
    Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
     Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("Getpath", "Cool" + mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}
```

Here I save my String to send it to my web service(REST)

```
private String setPic(ImageView v) throws IOException {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    targetW = 320;
    targetH = 250;

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (PICTURE_DNI){
        timeStapDNI = new Date().getTime();
    }else{
        timeStapSign =new Date().getTime();
    }

    File filePhoto = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePhoto);
    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis); // EXIF info lost
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    String  encodedPrueba = Base64.encodeToString(data,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.i("Data Input ", "" + encodedPrueba);
     v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return encodedPrueba;
}
```

The main problem is I'm losing EXIF.
Another way but is too slow to send it to web service:

```
File filePhoto = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) filePhoto.length()];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new 
FileInputStream(filePhoto));
dis.readFully(fileData);
dis.close();
String  encodedPrueba = Base64.encodeToString(fileData,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I'm using retrofit to send the information.The service have to receive a string for the file(encodedPrueba).

Comment: I forgot that I want to compress the file before to send it.

Comment: follow this...http://blog.aimanbaharum.com/2016/03/26/android-image-multi-part-upload/

Comment: I need to send it as String before to send it , Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

> The main problem is I'm losing EXIF.

Well, yes. A JPEG file may have EXIF information. A `Bitmap` does not. A JPEG created from a `Bitmap` does not, by default. You would need to read the EXIF information out of the original JPEG and add that same information (or adjusted if needed) to your new JPEG.

Comment: But this new JPEG wouldn't have the same size.

Comment: @JeanCarloFloresCarrasco: As I wrote, you would need to read the EXIF information out of the original JPEG and add that same information (**or adjusted if needed**) to your new JPEG. So, for any EXIF information that would need to change based upon your changes to the JPEG, you either need to calculate the new values or skip those EXIF tags.